# Remove InternalsVisibleTo for production

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, unit-testing, testing

Is it possible to disable `InternalsVisibleTo` for production & acceptance testing?

Whilst I would like to be able to poke internals at design time, I don't really want these exposed at higher level testing.

Comment: Why are your internals even visible to your acceptance tests?

Comment: @dcastro  They aren't, that's the point.  I want it removed at disabled at that point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the attribute in a [preprocessor directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx):

```
#if(DEBUG)
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("SomeAssembly")]
#endif
```

Comment: Good suggestion, hadn't thought of that.